# Spring Boot with MongoDB on Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, spring-boot

In these days, I am trying to deploy my Spring Boot OAuth2 project. It has 3 different modules.(Authentication Server, Resource Server and Front-end)
Authentication and Resource servers have own *.yml file for configurations such as mongodb name-port, server profile-ip etc.
What I am trying to do exactly? I want to deploy spring boot application on docker but i dont want to put my database(mongodb) on docker as a container.
**I am not sure this structure is possible or not ?** 
Because When i run my mongodb on my local(localhost:27017) after that try to deploy spring boot application on local docker as a container, i am getting **Timeout exception for MongoDB**. The application couldnt connect to external mongoDB(non docker container).

What should I do? Should I run mongodb on docker? I tried it also, Mongo runs successfully but still spring container couldnt run and connect to mongo.
I tried to run another spring boot app without mongodb, it is working successfully and i made request from browser by ip&port, i got response from application as i expected.

```
*** MONGO URL ****
mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/db-localhost

**** Authentication server .yml file   ****
server:
    port: 9080
    contextPath: /auth-service
    tomcat:
          access_log_enabled: true
          basedir: target/tomcat
security:
    basic:
        enabled: false
spring:
    profiles:
        active: development
    thymeleaf:
        cache: false
mongo:
    db:
      server: 127.0.0.1
      port: 27017
logging:
 level:
  org.springframework.security: DEBUG

---

spring:
  profiles: development
  data:
    mongodb:
      database: db-localhost

---

spring:
  profiles: production
  data:
    mongodb:
      database: db-prod

---


***** DOCKER FILE *******
FROM java:8
VOLUME /tmp
ADD auth-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 9080
RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]


**** DOCKER COMMAND *******
docker run -it -P --name authserver authserver
```

Comment: Both ways are possible . Can you share your docker file for mongodb and springboot along with docker run command ?

Comment: which url you are using for connect to mongo from container?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your configuration is referencing the mongodb from inside of the authservice on `127.0.0.1` which is the loopback adapter inside of the authservice container. So you tell your spring application that mongodb is running in the same container as the authservice spring application, which is not the case.

Either you are running your database as an own container (which requires to handle the data volumes correctly) and referencing it using the container name as hostname (via link) or you need to reference the externally running mongodb instance with the correct address. This would be the ip address of the machine running the docker daemon (I assume for your local environment something like `192.168.0.xxx`).

Comment: You said, my mongo url should be like this ; mongodb://192.168.99.100:27017/db-localhost     
Because my mongodb is running outside of the docker, on my local pc , not inside of the docker container, right ?

Comment: This looks like the ip address of a docker host vm. I assume you are using something like boot2docker. So there is your real host, the vm running docker and the containers itself. If your mongodb is installed directly on your host, this is not the correct address. Try to connect to your mongodb instance from your host's terminal not using the localhost or 127 address. This is then the ip to also use from inside.

Comment: ok I understand your point, but still its not clear for me because my mongodb is running on my local, not any other server or host. it means ip is 127.0.0.1. How can I tell the spring app which is in docker container, please spring app use my local mongodb(127.0.0.1) without  using 127.address ? i am a little bit confused at this point

Comment: The 127 address is like saying "on the same host". So think of me inviting you to "my house", you will surely not stay at your own house because that is what "my house" means for you. So instead of telling spring to use "my address" tell it the address of your real host. You can find out the name of your real host by running `ifconfig` in a new terminal window on your local machine. there is some entry for eth0 or wlan1 with an address like 192.168.0.x or 192.168.1.x in most cases.

Comment: Thank you so much @ajaegle. I understand my mistake. Now its working. I changed only mongo ip from 127.0.0.1 to 192.168.0.15

Answer (score 0):

**Question: What should I do?**

At least for developing purposes I would recommend to also use docker for your mongodb instance. I had a similar setup with RabbitMQ in addition and it solved a lot of problems when I used docker for those as well. Using  `docker-compose` to set everything up makes it even easier. Later you can still specify which mongodb instance you want to use through your spring properties.

**Problem: I tried it also, Mongo runs successfully but still spring container couldnt run and connect to mongo**

The problem is probably because you have not set up any networks or hostnames for you services. Your spring application can not resolve the hostname of your mongo server, since you specified `127.0.0.1` for your mongodb server in your properties.

I would recommend using docker for your mongodb and use a `docker-compose.yml` file like this to set everything up:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  resource-server:
    image: demo/resource-server:latest
    container_name: resource-server
    depends_on:
      - mongodb-example
    networks:
      - your-network
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  auth-server:
    image: demo/auth-server:latest
    container_name: auth-server
    depends_on:
      - mongodb-example
    networks:
      - your-network
    ports:
      - 8081:8080

  mongodb-example:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongo-example
    hostname: mongo-example
    networks:
      - your-network
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

networks:
  your-network:
    name: network-name
```

Of course you then need to adapt your property file or specify environment variables through your `docker-compose.yml` file.